# c3 graph key value pair

Tags: javascript, jquery, c3.js

So my brain is on shut down.

I have a c3 graph that accepts arrays of numbers so it can display the bars on the graph. I'm having trouble parsing the data that is coming from our backend into these arrays dynamically.

I have three variables

```
var inp = graphNums.inProgress;
var rec = graphNums.received;
var att = graphNums.attention;
```

That produces data in a key value pair that looks like this

```
{group1: 3, group2: 0, group3: 0}
```

These groups match with the x access along the bottom of the graph doing something like this.

```
for (i in inp) {
        if (inp.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            cat.push(i)
        }
    }
    cat.unshift('x'); //x needs to be there for the graph to work
```

Here is where the issue lies. The graph only accepts the values like this.

```
['Rec', 5, 1, 4, 8, 5, 3],
['InP', 7, 2, 7, 9, 7, 3],
['Res', 10, 5, 2, 9, 5, 2],
```

For the life of me I cannot figure out how to get the key value pair to match up with this array. Any help would be appreciated.

A jsfiddle with the full graph and example.
http://jsfiddle.net/17sqrnec/5/

Comment: i was checking your fiddle. could you explain again what the variables `inp`, `rec` and `res` mean/stand for; and also what would be a valid value for `cat`

Comment: @J.M.Echevarría Those are the open items that are in that status. So for group1, it would have a inp, rec and a res bar. The categories are actually correct in that fiddle. Each group would be a new category along the bottom of the graph. There could me multiple groups coming in, as many as 30 or more as much as I dislike that.

Comment: one last thing, AFAI understand, the `for` loop is just grabbing the indexes for the **x** axis (group1, group2 and group3), so in `var inp = {group1: 3, group2: 0, group3: 0};` what do the numbers **3**, **0** and **0** mean. also in `['Rec', 5, 1, 4, 8, 5, 3],` what are **5, 1, 4, 8, 5** and **3** for? the same goes to `['InP', 7, 2, 7, 9, 7, 3]` and `['Res', 10, 5, 2, 9, 5, 2]` cause I see not all of them are being displayed on hover

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to have a look at the documentation here : http://c3js.org/samples/data_json.html
You will find the JSON Format that can be used for categories, which would be for instance:

```
{category: 'cat1', group1: 3, group2: 0, group3: 0}
```

Comment: I have looked at that. I couldn't get it to work with the categories at the bottom of the graph though.

Comment: Maybe something like:
`['Rec', rec.group1, rec.group2, rec.group3],  ['InP', inp.group1, inp.group2, inp.group3], ['Res', res.group1, res.group2, res.group3]` could solve your problem?

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work in this case because I don't know what the categories are going to be until I grab them out of the first value and put them into an array. I could have three like above, or I could have 30.

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide an array with the `x` categories/labels
and remaining arrays will be considered *data* with a leading label, matching those of defined `x` categories

a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/17sqrnec/45/

Comment: This somewhat works. The one thing that keeps tripping me up though is that the bottom access needs to read the 'group1', 'group2', 'group3', ext and not the lblInp, lblRec, lblRes